# Is the Canon 7D compatible with all EF and EF-S lenses?

Tags: canon, autofocus, canon-7d

Are all the lenses compatible with 7d? Especially EF-S? 
Anyone having a autofocus issue with 55-250mm IS lens?

Comment: The question linked above should answer your basic question about compatibility, but it sounds like you're having an additional, specific problem with the 55-250mm lens. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I have a 7D and 55-250mm IS and they work fine together.

Comment: The 7D is fairly well known to have the worst frame-to-frame AF consistency of any of Canon's recent digital bodies. And not just with consumer grade lenses such as the 55-250mm lens.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer: Yes.**

All EF and EF-S lenes are compatible with your 7D. You should not have any autofocus problems if camera and lens work well.
Otherwise you should check the lens on an other eos (if you can) respectively the camera with other lenses.